# does the order on the Where statement hits the performance?

Tags: sql

Does the order you specify when constructing your query affects the performance? Or SQL does smart filtering.

For example assume I have a table Employee with 2 million records:

```
Employee( emp_id, name, dept_id, country_id )
```

not let's say I want  to get the id and name for those employees in  country id 500 and dept id 17.
Not lets say there about 300k  in that dept and about 1million in that country, however the result of those that met both criterions isw 50k.

Would it make a perfomance difference if I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
where dept_id = 17 and country_id= 500
```

than if I do:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM employees
    where  country_id= 500 and dept_id = 17
```

Assuming the latter will cut down the table to 1 million then do the rest from there  and 
the first query will cut down to 300k and do the 2nd filter from there.

However as mentioned before I'm unsure this is how the SQL motor handles the query.

Comment: If you don't have indices it would fall back to full table scan anyway.

Comment: You know, you can ask server to show you execution plan that will explain everything to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does affect, especially when you have residual predicates on your execution plan, but most of the time the query optimizer will do the job of reordering the predicates for you.

That assumes, of course, that your indexes and statistics are well-maintained and updated, so it's something to account for.

Further reading: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Selectivity_and_Column_Order

Answer (score 1):

Most modern RDMBS won't have a problem with the order of values in the `WHERE`-part of the statement, their query optimizers will in most cases sort it out the way you've described it to maximize the performance.

I know of a few older RDBMS who actually will be affected quite significant if you choose the "wrong" order, but those should be out of fashion for the last decade.

Answer (score 1):

In the above table,

if non-clustered index is there for -

(country_id,dept_id,employee_id) in the table,

then the query -

```
SELECT *
    FROM employees
    where  country_id= 500 and dept_id = 17
```

will have better performance.

and

if non-clustered index is there for -

(dept_id,country_id,employee_id) in the table,

then the query -

```
SELECT *
    FROM employees
    where  dept_id = 17 and country_id= 500
```

will have better performance.

If no non-clustered index is there,

then the query -

```
SELECT *
    FROM employees
    where  dept_id = 17 and country_id= 500
```

will have better performance for 2nd filtering subset is lower in number.

Also to mention,

If both the non-clustered index are there,

then the query -

```
SELECT *
    FROM employees
    where  dept_id = 17 and country_id= 500
```

will have better performance for 2nd filtering subset is lower in number.